# How to remove AM/PM from DateTime Column in SQl?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me, How to remove AM/PM from varchar datetime.

For example `2/14/2017 2:21:18 PM` , I want to remove PM from that.

I have DateTime as  a string  -

```
'2022-03-11 11:13:24 AM'
```

I want to remove AM/PM

I tried using this query but it is not working

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(src.[ApprovedDate],'AM',''),'PM','')
```

Comment: How is it not working, exactly? Your code seems fine (though I'd add a trailing space before the replacement terms).

Comment: I tried that as well but not working. Dont know the reason

Comment: But what do you mean when you say "not working". HOW is it not working? Does it throw an error? Does it show some unexpected results? It might also help if you provide details about which database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function of sql assuming your are in MS SQL world

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(src.[ApprovedDate] AS DATETIME),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
```

in MYSQL you could use [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

see [demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a279a1667f7b723a23bb8a54a3c310c7)

Comment: Tried this. Got Error
Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function

Comment: @SakshamSrivastava updated. This confirms you are using MS SQL server

Comment: @SakshamSrivastava check the demo link

Comment: Tried the updated one got error
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @SakshamSrivastava I believe that some of the data in the ApprovedDate column is not correct dates. I suggest maybe try this query `SELECT FORMAT(CAST(src.[ApprovedDate] AS DATETIME),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') WHERE TRY_CAST(src.[ApprovedDate] AS DATETIME) IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @SakshamSrivastava if above gives some rows as result then change the IS NOT NULL in where to IS NULL and see the bad data. You should then consider changing data type for the column so that data entry is correct or add client side code validations

Comment: Actually this is a sp so got error Incorrect syntax near 'WHERE' as it is inside the query.
Should i paste the the whole stored procedure

Comment: yes that will be helpful @SakshamSrivastava

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @myDatetime varchar(50);
SET @myDatetime = '2/14/2017 2:21:18 PM';
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(datetime, @myDatetime), 101) + ' ' + 
CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(datetime, @myDatetime), 108);
```

Comment: Not Working. Go same conversion to character string error.